# How to interpret regression coefficient if the dependent variable is reciprocal?

Tags: data-transformation, heteroscedasticity, weighted-regression

My regression models have heteroscedasticity problems. Gujarati (2008 and 2011) suggests that we can either transform one variable or do WLS. I choose transform by transforming my dependent variable to (1/Y) like what [this](http://stattrek.com/regression/linear-transformation.aspx?Tutorial=AP) tells me. The problem is I don't understand about how to interpret $\hat{Y} = \frac{1}{b_0 + b_1x}$.

My model is $Y = b_0 + b_1x_1 + b_2x_2 + b_3x_1x_2 + \varepsilon$

I transform into $\frac{1}{Y} =  b_0 + b_1x_1 + b_2x_2 + b_3x_1x_2 + \varepsilon$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my point of view this (nonlinear) transformation is not appropriate here, because with a random variable
$$Y_i=\mu_i + \epsilon_i $$ and $E(\epsilon_i)=0$ and $V(\epsilon_i)=\sigma_i^2$ we have $E(Y_i)=\mu_i$ and $V(Y_i)=\sigma_i^2$. If we transform the model by $f(Y)=Y^{-1}$ we have by the delta-method (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_method):
$$V(Y_i^{-1})\approx \sigma_i^2Y_i^{-4} $$ so the potential heteroscedasticity might have become even more severe as now $Y_i$ additionally enters!

I also would not recommend weighted least squares as you loose some nice properties as unbiasedness with this estimator.

Therefore I would suggest to stick with your specification

$Y=\beta_0 + \beta_1x_1 + \beta_2x_2+\beta_3x_1x_2 + \epsilon$

because you can interpret it easily and heteroscedasticity has no implications for the properties of unbiasedness and consistency of the OLS-Estimator. And in a second step you only correct the standard errors by using heteroscedasticity robust standard errors. Those are pretty easy to calculate with each statistical package capable to use matrix algebra and is also a standard implementation in most of them. For further information, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heteroscedasticity-consistent_standard_errors and have a look at the excellent book by Wooldridge on page 60 (https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/econometric-analysis-cross-section-and-panel-data).

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I understand the former part of your comment. However, I am afraid that I still can't grasp the understanding of the latter part especially when you stated "you can interpret it easily and heteroscedasticity has no implications for the properties of unbiasedness and consistency of the OLS-Estimator". Do you say that I can run interaction regression without checking heteroscedasticity? Could you please explain more?

Comment: No you sould clearly watch out for heteroscedasticity. But this is only an issue for inference and not for the parameter-estimation. For this reason I recommend to run the linear regression, interpret the parameter (also the interaction) as usual and when it comes to significance use heteroscedasticity robust standard errors.